# Merging specific elements of different lists to new list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, merge

I wrote a code like below. I generated uniform random variables of size 3,5 first. Then i used every element in this 2d array as a mean and generated new lists. What i want to make is create 10 new 2d array while using every element in list on same shape 3,5. For example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean_route1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(3,5)))
print(mean_route1)
N=10

for m in np.nditer(mean_route1):
    m3 = np.random.poisson(lam = m, size=N)
    print(m3)
```

The output is like that:

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  7.740569  5.435856  6.682996  5.213202  2.100649
1  6.174332  0.059057  2.951913  1.341994  2.734486
2  7.780503  7.277458  7.406986  8.498494  0.070157
[ 5  5  7  7  9  5  9 12  7  5]
[ 4  4  3  4 12  3  9  6  6  1]
[8 8 1 9 3 5 8 7 4 6]
[5 6 9 6 4 4 9 7 4 5]
[2 3 3 3 0 2 4 1 4 1]
[4 6 9 3 8 4 3 7 8 5]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[2 1 3 4 2 2 0 1 3 3]
[2 1 2 2 1 0 1 0 1 1]
[2 1 3 5 5 3 5 4 1 3]
[ 5  5  7  6  6  6 10 10  5  7]
[ 7  6  7  9  4 14  6  7  8  9]
[ 8 10  1  9 10  7  9  9  9 13]
[14  4  8 10  6  3 10  7 12  4]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

For example: What i want to do next is like 10 arrays like that: ( (:, 0) column on new first array like that.

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0         5         4         8         5         2
1         4         0         2         2         2
2         5         7         8        14         0
```

(:, 1) on new second array, ... , (:, 10) on new 10th array.

How can i do that? I am new on Python and stackoverflow so if i have an fault, i apologise.

Comment: I don't understand, could you please make a bit more clear how is your problem supposed to take the input values to generate the desired output?

Comment: I created 15 different list from mean values of mean_route1. I want to create 10 new (3,5) size DataFrame. For example;  using first element of each 15 list in first new (3,5)  size list. Using second elements of each 15 list in a second new (3,5) size list

Comment: So we can append everything into a huge list of 150 values, and make 10 dataframes out of the first 5 vvalues where they are the 1st row, the second 5 are the 2nd row and the third 5 values are the 3rd row.

Comment: are you saying that instead of 15 lists of length 10, you want 10 arrays of shape (3, 5)?

Comment: Yes Celius. That one will be the first dataframe. Then fourth 5 values where they are the second dataframe’s first row, the fifth 5 values where they are the second dataframe’s second row, ... go on like that. Totally there will be 10 dataframe with size (3,5)

Comment: I got you, working on it.

Comment: Yes and no Valentino. I want 10 array of shape (3,5) but while using the first elements of that 15 list in a first 3,5 array. Second columns of that 15 list in a second 3,5 array

Comment: Thank you very much Celius.

Comment: Why are you using `nditer`?  Why are you putting the initial  (3,5) array in a dataframe?  What does that do for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution using `numpy` features.

```
mean_route1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(3,5)))
print(mean_route1)
N=10

a = [np.random.poisson(lam = m, size=N) for m in np.nditer(mean_route1)]
b = np.stack(a)
c = [pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(arr, (3, 5))) for arr in b.T]
```

if you print `a`, `b` and `c` you will see that:

- `a` is composed by the rows you called `m3`, with a difference: is a list of ndarrays. The list has 15 elements, each element is a `ndarray` of length 10, generated by `np.random.poisson`.
- `b` is a stack of `a`. A 2D array whose rows are the arrays in `a`.
- `c` is your expected result, a list of datafames. Is created by transposing `b` (`b.T` is the transposed matrix) and iterating over each row of the transposed `b` (a column of the original `b`). Each row is reshaped into a (3, 5) matrix and converted into a pandas dataframe, and appended to `c`.

For example, if `a` is:

```
[array([5, 4, 6, 6, 3, 0, 2, 7, 5, 3]),
 array([ 3,  2,  5,  9,  6,  6,  8, 14,  3,  4]),
 array([ 1,  4,  2,  2, 10,  3,  4,  1,  5,  1]),
 array([ 8,  8,  3,  2,  4, 12,  3,  3,  2,  4]),
 array([5, 4, 1, 5, 8, 0, 4, 3, 5, 1]),
 array([ 3,  7,  7,  6, 12, 12, 10,  4,  2,  9]),
 array([4, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 7]),
 array([6, 8, 4, 6, 2, 7, 4, 4, 7, 7]),
 array([3, 7, 3, 4, 9, 4, 6, 5, 3, 3]),
 array([0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3]),
 array([4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 7, 8, 7]),
 array([11, 15, 11, 10,  7,  4,  5,  9, 14, 10]),
 array([10,  7,  9,  8,  7,  9,  8, 13,  8,  8]),
 array([7, 4, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 5, 8, 6])]
```

the first dataframe in `c` (`c[0]`) is:

```
   0  1   2   3  4
0  5  3   1   8  5
1  3  4   6   3  0
2  0  4  11  10  7
```

Answer (score 2):

Forgetting (for the moment) dataframes, with numpy we can do:

```
In [87]: mean_route1 = np.random.uniform(0,10,size=15)                                 
In [88]: alist = []                                                                    
In [89]: for m in mean_route1: 
    ...:     alist.append(np.random.poisson(lam=m, size=10)) 
    ...:                                                                               
In [90]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                         
In [91]: arr                                                                           
Out[91]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  2,  3,  2,  6,  7,  3,  7,  7,  5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  9,  8,  1,  6,  5,  6, 11,  6,  1],
       [16,  7,  9,  6,  6, 11, 11, 16,  9, 12],
       [ 3,  5,  2,  0,  2,  6,  4,  5,  3,  3],
       [ 5,  5,  8,  7,  9, 10,  5, 10,  7,  8],
       [ 5,  5,  4,  4,  2,  5,  1,  2,  1,  2],
       [ 4,  2,  6,  7,  2,  6,  5,  0,  1,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  4,  3,  2,  5,  7,  4,  5],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  0,  2,  0,  1,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  1,  3,  2,  0,  1,  1,  2],
       [ 9, 10, 10,  8,  9,  9,  9,  6, 12,  9]])
```

That is a (15,10) shape array, 10 samples each for the 15 `lam` values.  We can reshape that to (3,5,10) if you prefer, though that doesn't change the values.

```
In [92]: arr.reshape(3,5,10)                                                           
Out[92]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 4,  2,  3,  2,  6,  7,  3,  7,  7,  5],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 7,  9,  8,  1,  6,  5,  6, 11,  6,  1],
        [16,  7,  9,  6,  6, 11, 11, 16,  9, 12]],

       [[ 3,  5,  2,  0,  2,  6,  4,  5,  3,  3],
        [ 5,  5,  8,  7,  9, 10,  5, 10,  7,  8],
        [ 5,  5,  4,  4,  2,  5,  1,  2,  1,  2],
        [ 4,  2,  6,  7,  2,  6,  5,  0,  1,  4],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 5,  5,  5,  4,  3,  2,  5,  7,  4,  5],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  0,  2,  0,  1,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  6,  1,  3,  2,  0,  1,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 10,  8,  9,  9,  9,  6, 12,  9]]])
```

By starting with (15,) rather than (3,5) I can do a simple iteration, without the complications of `nditer`. (I discourage the use of `nditer`, unless you really need some special features.  It isn't faster.)

I could construct 10 dataframes from that (3,5,10) array with a loop like:

```
In [94]: import pandas as pd                                                           
In [95]: for i in range(3): 
    ...:     print(pd.DataFrame(_92[:,:,i]))   # Out[92] array
    ...:                                                                               
   0  1  2  3   4           # 1st column
0  0  4  0  7  16
1  3  5  5  4   0
2  5  1  0  0   9

   0  1  2  3   4           # 2nd column
0  0  2  0  9   7
1  5  5  5  2   0
2  5  1  0  0  10

   0  1  2  3   4
0  0  3  0  8   9
1  2  8  4  6   0
2  5  1  0  6  10
```

I can call `poisson` with all the `mean_route1` values at once:

```
In [97]: np.random.poisson(lam=mean_route1, size=(10,15))                              
Out[97]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  0,  4, 11,  5,  9,  2,  8,  0, 10,  0,  0,  1,  5],
       [ 0,  4,  0,  3,  9,  3, 11,  3,  4,  0,  4,  0,  2,  0,  7],
       [ 0,  4,  0,  4,  6,  1,  7,  4,  2,  0,  5,  1,  0,  0,  5],
       ...
       [ 0,  9,  0,  6, 12,  3,  3,  5,  3,  0,  6,  1,  1,  1,  6]])
```

or transposing to the (15,10) I got in `Out[91]`:

```
In [98]: np.random.poisson(lam=mean_route1, size=(10,15)).T                            
Out[98]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  4,  5,  6,  7,  1,  6,  2,  0,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  4,  6,  3,  9,  1, 10,  3,  4],
       ....
       [10,  8,  5, 13,  7, 10,  5, 10,  7,  9]])
```

Or with a (3,5) array of `lam`:

```
In [100]: np.random.poisson(lam=mean_route1.reshape(3,5), size=(10,3,5))               
Out[100]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  0,  2,  9],
        [ 1,  7,  2,  6,  0],
        [ 3,  0,  0,  1, 10]],

       [[ 0,  5,  0,  7,  8],
        [ 2,  6,  2,  8,  0],
        [ 5,  2,  0,  1, 11]],

       [[ 0,  7,  0,  7, 11],
        [ 2,  7,  2,  4,  0],
        [ 7,  1,  1,  1, 10]],
      ....
        [ 7,  1,  1,  3, 12]]])
```

Again, making the dataframes, this time iterating on the 1st dimension:

```
In [101]: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     print(pd.DataFrame(_100[i,:,:])) 
     ...:                                                                              
   0  1  2  3   4
0  0  1  0  2   9
1  1  7  2  6   0
2  3  0  0  1  10

   0  1  2  3   4
0  0  5  0  7   8
1  2  6  2  8   0
2  5  2  0  1  11

   0  1  2  3   4
0  0  7  0  7  11
1  2  7  2  4   0
2  7  1  1  1  10
```

Answer (score 1):

See if you can help me here, I've managed to create d, which is the inputs for each dataframe, you should now create dataframes with each sub-list in d. I'll try to work on it too, but this is far as I can go for the moment:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mean_route1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(3,5)))
print(mean_route1)
N=10
a = []
c = []
for m in np.nditer(mean_route1):
    m3 = list(np.random.poisson(lam = m, size=N))
    print(m3)
    a.append(m3)
```

Here's the output of each list:

```
[4, 6, 8, 12, 4, 10, 8, 7, 9, 13]
[12, 11, 12, 8, 9, 4, 7, 10, 11, 6]
[2, 1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 3, 0, 3]
[4, 4, 7, 2, 9, 3, 9, 5, 10, 11]
[6, 9, 11, 6, 10, 14, 14, 6, 10, 7]
[5, 7, 4, 8, 4, 7, 9, 3, 6, 2]
[3, 3, 4, 7, 5, 7, 5, 4, 2, 3]
[6, 3, 6, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 1]
[6, 5, 7, 6, 5, 8, 10, 6, 8, 4]
[3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 5]
[5, 5, 5, 2, 6, 11, 8, 13, 6, 11]
[4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 6, 8, 6]
[7, 5, 11, 3, 8, 7, 5, 10, 3, 7]
[12, 5, 7, 10, 8, 4, 5, 6, 8, 4]
```

Now I create big list with all the values, but in the order you requested, kinda like 'transposing' the lists.

```
for b in range(10):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c.append(a[i][b])
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[4, 12, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 6, 1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 7, 12, 6, 11, 1, 4, 9, 7, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 8, 12, 2, 7, 11, 4, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 11, 7, 12, 8, 0, 2, 6, 8, 7, 4, 1, 6, 4, 2, 4, 3, 10, 4, 9, 4, 9, 10, 4, 5, 7, 0, 5, 5, 6, 4, 8, 8, 10, 4, 3, 3, 14, 7, 7, 3, 2, 8, 3, 11, 4, 7, 4, 8, 7, 2, 9, 14, 9, 5, 4, 4, 10, 2, 8, 7, 5, 5, 7, 10, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 13, 6, 10, 6, 9, 11, 0, 10, 10, 6, 2, 4, 0, 8, 1, 6, 8, 3, 8, 13, 6, 3, 11, 7, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 11, 6, 7, 4]
```

Subsestting this big list in groups of 15s to be used for the new dataframes:

```
d = []
for i in range(10):
    d.append(c[(i)*15:((i+1)*15)])
print(d)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 12, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3, 6, 1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 7, 12], [6, 11, 1, 4, 9, 7, 3, 3, 1, 5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5], [8, 12, 2, 7, 11, 4, 4, 6, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 11, 7], [12, 8, 0, 2, 6, 8, 7, 4, 1, 6, 4, 2, 4, 3, 10], [4, 9, 4, 9, 10, 4, 5, 7, 0, 5, 5, 6, 4, 8, 8], [10, 4, 3, 3, 14, 7, 7, 3, 2, 8, 3, 11, 4, 7, 4], [8, 7, 2, 9, 14, 9, 5, 4, 4, 10, 2, 8, 7, 5, 5], [7, 10, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 13, 6, 10, 6], [9, 11, 0, 10, 10, 6, 2, 4, 0, 8, 1, 6, 8, 3, 8], [13, 6, 3, 11, 7, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 11, 6, 7, 4]]
```

Finally to create each dataframe this is what I would do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'row1':d[0][:5],'row2':d[0][5:10],'row3':d[0][10:15]}).T
print(df1)
        0   1   2   3   4
row 1   4   12  2   4   6
row 2   5   3   6   1   6
row 3   3   5   4   7   12
```

And probably repeat this process for each index-value in list `d` for the 15 sub-lists composing `d`. This feels far from optimal, but is how I managed to solve the problem.